# execute script on remote machine

Tags: bash

I have bunch of script files that I need to execute on the remote machine. The script files start with the server names. They are located on /opt/local directory

for example

```
server1.sh
server2.sh
server3.sh
```

using a loop, I need to go through each file.

1. extract name from the list (e.g. server1)
2. append .example.com after the name of the server1
3. ssh user1@server1.example.com
4. execute /opt/local/server1.sh
5. if successful write to /opt/files/success.log, server1.sh successfully executed
   6.if not successful write to /opt/files/errors.log, server1.sh not successful including unable to login, unable to execute script or something like this.

'''

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/opt/local
for f in $FILES
do
  name="${FILE%%.*}"
  name="${name}.example.com"
  ssh user1@name "bash -s" ./${f}

done
```

'''

Comment: What you have looks really close. I can see you are missing the glob `*` in the for loop.

Comment: what about writing to the log files?

Comment: @jordanm, how do I write to the logs?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
MYNAME=$(basename $0)
WRKDIR=/opt/local
SUF=".sh"
# LOGDIR: create and set permissions for user before running this script
LOGDIR="/var/log/$MYNAME"
LOGFILE="$LOGDIR/$MYNAME-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').log"
exec 1>>$LOGFILE
exec 2>&1
find $WRKDIR -name "*$SUF" | while read SCRIPTNAME
do
   SERVER=$(basename $SCRIPTNAME $SUF)
   echo "$(date): started $SERVER ..."
   URL="$SERVER.example.com"
   echo CMD: ssh user1@$URL "bash -s" $SCRIPTNAME \
   && ssh user1@$URL "bash -s" $SCRIPTNAME
   echo "$(date): done $SERVER"
   echo "------------------------------------"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script could look like this:

```
dir=/opt/local
for file in "$dir"/*; do
     # extract name from the list (e.g. server1)
     name="${file%%.*}"
     # append .example.com after the name of the server1
     addr="${name}.example.com"
     # execute /opt/local/server1.sh
     if ssh "user1@$addr" "bash -s" < "$file"; then
          # if successful write to /opt/files/success.log server1.sh successfully executed 6
          printf "%s %s\n" "$name" "successfully executed 6" >> /opt/files/success.log
     else
         # if not successful write to /opt/files/errors.log, server1.sh not successful including unable to login, unable to execute script or something like this.
         printf "%s %s\n" "$name" "not successful including unable to login, unable to execute script or something like this" >> /opt/files/error.log
     fi
done
```